# Extracting text from a HTML to be stored as a JS variable, then to be added to a separate HTML's element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alrite, I have seen other Questions with similar titles but they don't do exactly what Im asking.
I have 2 x HTML documents, one containing my page, one containing a element with a paragraph of text in it. As-well as a separate .js file 
what I want to do is extract this text, store it as a JS variable and then use jQuery to edit the contents of an element within the main page. This is the conclusion I came to but it didnt work as expected, im not sure if it is me making a syntax error or if i am using the wrong code completely:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var c1=(#homec.substring(0)) 
     // #homec is the container of the text i need 
    $(".nav_btn #1").click(function(c1){ 
         $(".pcontent span p") .html(+c1)} 
);
```

});
i know +c1 is most probably wrong, but i have been struggling to find the syntax on this one. thankyou in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

`var c1=(#homec.substring(0))` will throw an error because #homec is not a valid variable name, is undefined, and does not have a property function called `substring`. To get the html of an element with an id of `homec`, use the `html` method:

```
var c1 = $("#homec").html();
```

`c1` should not be an argument of the click function because it is defined in the parent scope. `+c1` is unnecessary because you do not need to coerce `c1` to a number.

If you are trying to add content to the end of the paragraph, use the `append` method:

```
$(".pcontent span p").append(c1)
```

That means you should use this code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var c1 = $("#homec").html();
  $(".nav_btn #1").click(function() {  
     $(".pcontent span p").append(c1)
  }); 
});
```

P.S. Numbers are not valid ID attributes in HTML. Browsers support it, so it won't make anything go awry, but your pages won't validate.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have tried your suggestion but still I am getting no text in .pcontent . i did look at append but what im looking to do is replace all text in .pcontent so im guessing .html is the best way to go. im trying to use JS to update a single page in the HTML

Comment: If you `alert($("#homec").html())`, does it show anything? If it does, then it should be appending correctly. It looked like you were canting to append, because your example showed `+c1`, but if you are wanting to replace, then yes, `html` is the method you should use.

Comment: it didnt even come up with an alert box, so i assume it's not even attempting to run the code. im not doubting your code btw, im doubting whether i have linked it correctly

Comment: could it be because i am using 2 external javascript and attempting to extract from  HTML into another seperate HTML or should this work?

Comment: Does ".nav_btn #1" exist, or are you adding it programmatically?

Comment: yes it does, it already has another click event assigned to it and its been working fine. so I cant imagine it is a problem with that, unless i should not have put the id and class in the same quotes?

Comment: i just removed the #1 and now im getting the alert box, but its value is null

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean by two HTML documents....you can only have one page open at once, unless you are using IFRAMEs.

Comment: The HTML I am trying to extract from is just saved as HTML i was just using it to store the text, does the page actually need to be actively open for the Javascript to access it?

Comment: Yes. Javascript can only acces HTML if it is open on the page or in an IFRAME, or is obtained with an AJAX request.

Comment: o alrite. yeah i know what to do now. if i use an XML doc instead and use AJAX to retrieve it it should work then. Thanks for your time peter

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery `text()` function will allow you to get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants. You can then use the `text(value)` function to set the text content of your target paragraph element. Something like this should suffice:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var c1 = $("homec").text();
    $(".nav_btn #1").click(function() { 
        $(".pcontent span p").text(c1);
    });
});
```

See the JQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for more details on the `text()` function. If you need to capture the full structure of the other document, then try the `html()` function instead.

Comment: Any chance someone could explain the downvote. I'd be very interested in feedback. Thanks, T

Comment: The second line was missing the JQuery `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".nav_btn #1").click(function(c1){           
    var para = $(".pcontent span p");
    para.html(para.html() + c1);
    });
```